# Creating a stacked bar chart using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data, which i would like to visualize as a stacked bar plot.

```
sample <- tibble(
Month = c("1/1/2019","2/1/2019","3/1/2019","4/1/2019","5/1/2019","6/1/2019","7/1/2019","8/1/2019","9/1/2019","10/1/2019","11/1/2019","12/1/2019","1/1/2020","2/1/2020","3/1/2020"),
Apples = c(38,  33,31,27,   30, 34, 33, 39, 33, 23, 24, 21, 23, 23,30),
Oranges = c(20,32,21,15,23,10,13,37,66,48,60,16,36,25,29),
Shopping = c(58,65,52,42,53,44,46,76,99,71,84,37,59,48,59)
)
```

So, apples + oranges = shopping. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
plotdata <- sample %>%
                       select(-Shopping) %>% 
                       pivot_longer(-Month)
ggplot(plotdata,aes(x=Month,y=value,fill=name)) +
    geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","orange"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ian.Can you please show me how to change colors as well?

Comment: I edited my answer with custom colors.